Custom emojis / shapes in ggplot failing to render, show up as rectangles
I am trying to play around with custom icons for my ggplot, and found a useful post that included the following code. However, when I run this, I don't see hearts.

library(ggplot2)
df <- read.table(text="x y
                 1    3
                 2    4
                 3    6
                 4    7", header=TRUE) 

ggplot(data = df, aes(x =x, y=y)) +  
  geom_point(shape="\u2764",
             colour = "red",
             fill = "white",
             size = 6)

I ran the above code and expected what you see here: Custom shape in ggplot (geom_point) - use brain emoji 🧠
But instead I see rectangles (https://i.sstatic.net/26V5C26M.png)

Thanks so much! This worked (after I restarted my R session) but now when I try to plot these alongside a specific font I have to use for the text, the problem reverts.
Basically, I have to use this specific font which I load using the following:
library(showtext) #might have to install this first
font_add_google("lexend", "lexend")
showtext::showtext_auto()
showtext::showtext_opts(dpi = 300)
Once I do that, it shows the correct font type but it the emojis turn back into rectangles... any ideas?

If you're using RStudio, try to change the Graphics Device Backend in Tools > Global Options > Genral > Graphics. If I use Quartz or Cairo I get rectangles, if I use Cairo PNG or  AGG, I get hearts.

Thanks so much! This worked (after I restarted my R session) but now when I try to plot these alongside a specific font I have to use for the text, the problem reverts. Basically, I have to use this specific font which I load using the following: library(showtext) #might have to install this first font_add_google("lexend", "lexend") showtext::showtext_auto() showtext::showtext_opts(dpi = 300) Once I do that, it shows the correct font type but it the emojis turn back into rectangles... any ideas? –

I can confirm that aftter running showtext::showtext_auto(), the emojhi displays as a rectangle. That appears to be an open issue. https://github.com/yixuan/showtext/issues/54.
